# jqGrid recreateForm parameter

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to know where is the correct ubication of the following sentence: 
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {recreateForm: true}).

I found here that setting it, you can solve problems with edition of rows, when you are using custom edittype columns, in respect of these type of fields don't refresh between successive editing records. But I proved it without positive results.
I'm using form editing.

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {recreateForm: true});
```

is the correct code to change default value of `recreateForm` to `true`. You can find in [my answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-change-the-recreateform/) in the forum of http://www.trirand.com other different variation to set `recreateForm` to `true`.

If this will not help you, you have probably another problem in your code. You can append your question with the code which can be used to reproduce your problem. I or somebody else could try to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks Oleg, I followed your advice and append new question with the code. I greatly appreciate your time.